# Why is a COUNT in CosmosDB more expensive than listing the actual documents?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I tried a query like:
`SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c WHERE <a few equality conditions and a 'date greater than' condition>`
on a partitioned collection (cross-partition query).

I also tried `SELECT * FROM c WHERE <same conditions>`

To my surprise, the `SELECT *` version cost less than `SELECT VALUE COUNT(1)`:

- for 1 returned doc:   17 RU vs 21 RU
- for 45 returned docs: 22 RU vs 460 RU !!

Does anyone have an explanation on why this happens?

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't be the case. Can you share the specific query, how you are running it, and what is the indexing policy on the container?

Answer (score 0):

Though it's a very old question but still adding this answer in case someone comes here searching.

I also faced the same issue `select count(1) FROM c WHERE <same conditions>`, `select count(*) FROM c WHERE <same conditions>` and `select count(c.id) FROM c WHERE <same conditions>` were all taking more RUs than doing `select * FROM c WHERE <same conditions>`

There are 2 solutions to this (that we found by hit and trial and many email exchanges with the Cosmos Db support team)

1. use `select top 1 c.id FROM c WHERE <same conditions>` and change the code to use it as a binary output
2. use something that is indexed in both the where clause and the select count field. e.g. `select count(c.indexedField) from c where c.indexedField = "xyz"`

The Cosmos DB team mentioned that they are fixing it so in the future we might not need to do this optimization ourselves. I wish that they had mentioned it somewhere in the documentation.